# How do i pass a `Vec<u8>` as argument to a contracts function, using the command line(cargo contract)

Tags: ink, rust, smart-contract, cargo-contract

When using cargo contract to call contracts, in all the examples i've seen, its either been `AccountId` or `bool`ean or `integers(u & i)`. I need to pass a `Vec<u8>` to my contract function. I've been trying but it all results into errors. Please can you help show me how its done.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how i solved it:
I converted all the array elements to an hexadecimal string. You can check out the [hex crate](https://docs.rs/hex/latest/hex/index.html) e.g
`[20, 103, 114, 101, 97, 116]` = `0x` + `146772656174`(hex string)

Make sure to add `0x` to the string before sending it as a parameter.

```
 Result Success!
    Reverted false
        Data Tuple(Tuple { ident: Some("Ok"), values: [Seq(Seq { elems: [UInt(20), UInt(103), UInt(114), UInt(101), UInt(97), UInt(116)] })] })
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated here:

- https://gitlab.parity.io/sergejparity/cargo-contract/-/issues/517

Try escaping:

```
cargo contract instantiate \
       --constructor new \
       --args 3 \[5FKy7RwXBCCACCEPjM5WugkhUd787FjdgieTkdj7TPngJzxN] \
       --suri //Alice \
       --code-hash 0xbc1b42256696c8a4187ec3ed79fc602789fc11287c4c30926f5e31ed8169574e
```

Comment: Once i add more than one element into the array, i throws errors.

Comment: Actually, i'm thinking it's the sclae-encoding that should be submitted, instead of the raw thing